# MATLAB C S-function cannot be compiled in simulink real time

Tags: simulink, matlab-compiler

I used C S-function in Simulink real time. When compiling the model, the following errors occurred,
*“mxCreateDoubleScalar”is not defined;
“mexPutVariable”is not defined；
<"mxSetCell_ is_ not_ supported_ in_ Simulink_ Coder ": undeclared identifier*
[enter image description here][1]

I know that Simulink real time doesn't seem to support “mxCreateDoubleScalar”、“mexPutVariable”, but I don't know how to replace it, can you help me?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtiyo.png

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to work with executables. First you have to have installed a C/C++ compiler. I recommend you to install minGW (you can get it on the AddOn of Matlab).
Then, you have to initialize all the variables that you are using on the s-function.
For last, when you want to make a "mex" with your model and s-function, check the command line to mex all files. I had the same problem 2 years ago and I was able to create a real-time application and run it.

Here you have how to use the `mex` function [mex function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html)

Here you have the information about the C/C++ compiler [C/C++ compiler](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/52848-matlab-support-for-mingw-w64-c-c-compiler)

Here you have the information about how configurate your .mdl or .slx [Simulink Real-Time](https://www.mathworks.com/products/simulink-real-time.html#simulation)

I suggest you to post this question on the Matlab's forum, possibly they could help you better.

BR.

PD: If you have .h files linked with your .c file, make sure that on the mex command line you are linking all this files.